# ¿Por qué no puedo agregar más objetos?

Tags: javascript, json

¿Cómo está? El día de hoy vengo por esta pregunta:

¿Cómo hago para agregar más objetos a un objeto, en específico a un array?.

Este es mi código.

```js
//import db from './d36.json';
const fs = require('fs');
const gola = require('./d36.json');

function dataWrites(ruta, data) {
  fs.writeFile(ruta, data, (err) => {
    err ? console.error('Salio Mal') : console.error('Todo bien');
  });
}

let datoss =
  gola
    .map((i) => i.Country_Region)
    .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);

let sadasdas = Object.values(datoss);
let prueba = {
  data: {
    country: datoss,
  },
};

dataWrites(__dirname + '/d1.json', JSON.stringify(prueba));
```

Me funciona de maravilla, y  me arroja el resultado:

```js
{"data":{"country":["US","Italy","Brazil"]}}
```

Mi intencíón es agregarle mas valores al objeto, quedaría como algo así:

```js
{"data":{"country":["US":{"title":"valor"},"Italy":{"title":"valor","Brazil":{"title":"valor"]}}
```

Mis intentos de soluciones fueron estas:

```js
  // 1
    country: datoss.map((el) => {Object.assign(el): {"title":"valor"}} ),

    // 2
    country: datoss.map((el) => el: {"title":"valor"}),
  // 3 
  country: {
      ...Object.keys(datoss).map(
        (e) =>
          (Object.assign(datoss[e]) = {
            2: 's',
          })
      ),
    },
```

No sé que hacer, llevo gran parte de la noche en esto :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error que cometes es principalmente la sintaxis de JSON. En este caso el error también ocurre con un *JavaScript object*.

```
[
    'US': { 'title': 'value' },
    ...
]
```

Esto es incorrecto. Los elementos del *array* no pueden tener una *key* que asignes tú. Un *array* al final es un *object* cuyas *keys* son números de `0` a `n`, donde `n` es la longitud del *array*.
Lo que tú tratas de hacer es añadir objetos en el *array*. Cada objeto tendrá una *key* (el país) y un objeto como valor de esa *key*.

Te propongo dos formas de hacerlo.

Partiendo del *array* original

```
const country = [ 'US', 'Italy', 'Brazil'];
```

... usar el método `map`, como ya estabas usando. Esta es la forma funcional de hacerlo.

```
// Crea un objeto con key c (el country)
// cuyo valor es un objecto con una key y un value
const withMap = (key, value) =>
    country.map(c => ({ [c]: { [key]: value } }));

const result = withMap('title', 'value');
console.log(result);
// [
//     { US: { title: 'value' } },
//     { Italy: { title: 'value' } },
//     { Brazil: { title: 'value' } }
// ]
```

La forma no-funcional consistirá entonces en ir modificando el *array* original.

```
const addProperty = (element, key, value) => {
    // Si no lo encuentra, sale de la función
    if (! country.some(c => c === element)) 
        return;

    // Construye el nuevo objeto
    // Basado en el elemento
    // Y como valor el objeto { key: value }
    const obj = {
        [element]: { [key]: value }
    };

    // Asigna a country el resultado
    // del array original excepto el elemento a modificar
    // Y agrega el nuevo objeto
    country = [...country.filter(c => c !== element), obj];
}

addProperty('US', 'title', 'Washington DC');
addProperty('Italy', 'title', 'Roma');
addProperty('Brazil', 'title', 'Brasilia');
console.log(country);
// [
//     { US: { title: 'Washington DC' } },
//     { Italy: { title: 'Roma' } },
//     { Brazil: { title: 'Brasilia' } }
// ]
```

De esta forma puedes añadir diferentes *keys* y *values* si es necesario.
O hacer una función para cambiar de una todos los elementos.

```
const addAll = (key, value) =>
    country.forEach(c => addProperty(c, key, value));

addAll('title', 'value');
console.log(country);
// [
//     { US: { title: 'value' } },
//     { Italy: { title: 'value' } },
//     { Brazil: { title: 'value' } }
// ]
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Genial respuesta. Lo único que cambiaría sería la primera línea, ya que no es lo mismo JavaScript Object que JSON (aunque estén muy relacionados). JSON es la notación, un estándar para serializar un objeto con una sintaxis **parecida** a la que se usa para describir un objeto en JavaScript. Un ejemplo por el cual se puede ver que no son exactamente iguales sería: `{ 'key' : 'value' }`. Esa sintaxis sería válida para un objeto de JavaScript, pero no sería sintaxis válida de JSON (son obligatorias las comillas dobles).

Comment: Sí, toda la razón @ordago. Me refería más bien a que en este caso es lo mismo, se aplica el mismo error tanto en la sintaxis JSON como en un *JavaScript object*. Voy a editar la respuesta para evitar confusiones. Gracias.